# Creating a Message Box with Scrollable window in python using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code which should display text in a scrollable window. I need two buttons on the scrollable window and hence I am using askokcancel().

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tix
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

class Window:

    def __init__(self, root,msg):

        self.myMainContainer = Frame(width=500,height=500)
        self.myMainContainer.pack()
        #self.myMainContainer.grid(row=0, column=0)

        scrwin = Tix.ScrolledWindow(self.myMainContainer, scrollbar='y') 
        scrwin.pack()
        #scrwin.grid(row=0, column=0) 
        self.win = scrwin.window
        w = tkMessageBox.askokcancel('this', msg)
        print w


link = 'http://www.mnemonicdictionary.com/word/'
word = 'scrap'
r = urllib.urlopen(link+word)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
result = soup.find_all('div',id='home-middle-content')
text = str(result[0].get_text().encode('utf-8')).replace('\n','')
print text
root = Tix.Tk()
myWindow = Window(root,text)

root.mainloop()
```

However I get two windows : One containing the text and the other containing the scroll bar. How do I combine them ?

Kindly Help...

Comment: You can't combine them. You either create a custom dialog with the widgets you want, or you use the built-in dialog.

Comment: The Tkinter Scrollbar Widget: This widget is used to implement scrolled listboxes, canvases, and text fields.
The Scrollbar widget is almost always used in conjunction with a Listbox, Canvas, or Text widget. Horizontal scrollbars can also be used with the Entry widget.
-[Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm)

Comment: @BryanOakley I am not able to make out anything using the documentation. Could you please help ?

Comment: Start here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm

Comment: @BryanOakley From the above I removed tkMessageBox and instead added Message() and  two manual Button(). Every thing is fine when text is small. however the buttons disappear when I add a longer paragraph (which has to be scrolled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sure, which version of `Python` and `Tkinter`, you are using. But If I have to do something like this now, with `python3`, I will do it like below.

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter.constants import END

class SampleDialog(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.root=Toplevel(parent)
        self.text = ScrolledText(self.root)
        self.text.insert(END, "a\nb\na\nb\na\nb\na\nb\na\nb\na\nb\na\nb\na\nb\na\nb\na\nb\na\nb\na\nb\na\nb\na\nb\na\nb\na\nb\na\nb\n")
        self.text.pack()
        self.ok = Button(self.root, text="ok", command=self.onOk)
        self.ok.pack()
        self.root.wait_visibility()
        self.root.grab_set()
        self.root.transient(parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def onOk(self):
        self.root.grab_release()
        self.root.destroy()

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, window):
        Button(window, text='dialog', command=self.onDialog).pack()
        Button(window, text='exit', command=self.onExit).pack()
        self.window = window

    def onDialog(self):
        d = SampleDialog(self.window)
        self.window.wait_window(d.root)   # <<< NOTE

    def onExit(self):
        self.window.destroy()

root = Tk()
app = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```